# Hide Print Queue window during Processing sketch (present mode) in Mac OS X 10.10.3

Tags: macos, printing, processing, system-preferences

Put together Processing sketch for an exhibition. Users type their input - Processing saves as .txt file to a folder - Folder action prints to a thermal receipt printer automatically.

My problem is since updating the OS X (10.10.3) (which I had to do. It was a college mac and Processing 2 wouldn't run on OS X 10.6), the **print queue window pops up over the sketch**. Can't seem to find a way for this not to display, just run in the background. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the help of a great little article in CNET - "Keep applications from stealing focus when opening in OS X." Followed the steps for launching programmes behind others with the print driver and it works a charm.

http://www.cnet.com/uk/news/keep-applications-from-stealing-focus-when-opening-in-os-x/